# Compile moment.js with google closure and advanced optimizations

Tags: momentjs, google-closure-compiler

I work on a project which uses Google's closure compiler with advanced optimizations turned on. I would like to include moment.js in the compilation, however all of my attempts have been fruitless.

I have tried exporting the moment function, but there are still run time problems, and a some compile errors.

Has anyone successfully compiled moment.js with advanced optimizations, or know how to do so?

The only solution I can come up with, is to concatenate the minified file to the compiled source and use externs for every function I use from moment.js. But this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw two issues with the code which would have to be corrected before momentjs would be compatible with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS. There may be more, but these were the glaring ones:

1. Using an alias for the prototype: All references to `.fn` would need to be replaced with `.prototype`.
2. Using a helper function to add methods: the `extend` method hides definitions from the compiler. All uses of the `extend` helper function would have to be refactored so that they do not hide the property assignments from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it to work either as of 26 March 2015, but the existence of [this](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/moment) suggests that it's possible. [Here are the externs](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/moment)

Comment: clojure is not the same as Google Closure Compiler, which is what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta write your own externs file for moment.js for what you use from it (or the entire object, but I find that a bit of extra work for no reason).

For example, I've got this snippet to test if an input's date is within 14 days from now

```
$checkout.find('.date-input').on('input', /** @this {Element} */ function () {
    const $this = $(this);
    const Days = Number($this.attr('data-days'));
    if (Days > 0 && moment(/** @type {string} */($this.val())).diff(moment(), 'days') < Days) {
        $checkout.find('.date-warning').removeClass('d-none');
    } else {
        $checkout.find('.date-warning').addClass('d-none');
    }
});
```

And the only way I'd get that to compile correctly with advanced mode is by creating this extern.

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Externs for moment
 *
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * @param {string=} date
 * @constructor
 * @return {!moment}
 */
function moment(date) {}

/**
 * @param {!moment} m
 * @param {string} unit
 * @return {number}
 */
moment.diff = function (m, unit) {};
moment.prototype.diff = moment.diff;
```

Now clearly that description of the moment function isn't perfect; it's missing some parameters that the moment function has, but I'm not using them so it doesn't matter to me.

But that's how I start my externs. I start basic as the need arises and then I continue to grow the externs file with the more functions I need from a library.

And don't forget to tell Closure Compiler where your extern is located with the flag `--externs 'externs/moment.js'`.